# Publicize SFSE at Dreamforce?

Tags: discussion

Dreamforce is next week!  How can we use the opportunity to spread the word about SFSE and build our community?

Ideas:

- Mention it in lots of conversations
- Write "Ask me about SF StackExchange" on our name badges -- people will be looking at them all the time
- Print business cards to give out but we'd need a ton (we're probably too late in the game to print them, and would need a ton)
- Bring it up on Chatter

Other ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually put in a proposal for the Unconference in the DevZone to talk about this site, that's been picked up and it looks as though I'll be doing two small chats about, one on the Tuesday and one on the Friday:

http://dfdevzoneunconf.uservoice.com/forums/172153-dreamforce-2012-devzone-unconference/suggestions/3108925-what-is-this-new-fangled-salesforce-stack-exchange

Chances are I'll be sporting my Stack Exchange t-shirt I was sent when promoting the original proposal, and I'll have a bunch of stickers too — if everybody grabs some and starts slapping them about the place we'll get the user base up in no time ;)

As for business cards, I have some for my blog which I'll use for that purpose—I've bit a banner for the site on the side to take people through to it.

Comment: Seems your way ahead of all of us :)

Comment: Those will be in the Developer Lounge, right? If so, I might be able to make Tuesday's session.

Comment: Gah! I'll be presenting a workshop until 10:30am on Friday!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to spray paint a SFDC logo on my head ... if people talk to me I'll tell them to look me up here (;

I'll also mention it during the session I'm speaking at.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth contacting the DF Dev Zone team and seeing if they might be willing to help out with the 'Publicising'.

It may be help as simple as getting them to add SFSE to the list of 'resources' they mention to people who ask them about complex issues. (like the SF dev boards)

Also is anyone here giving a Dev Zone talk that could slip an extra slide in at the end?

I tweeted @adamse and he suggested that we get SFSE on the unconference agenda:

> @Helastel_Jon @samantha_ready we have an unconference - add it to the
>   proposals and the community can vote it up and get engaged!

http://dfdevzoneunconf.uservoice.com/forums/172153-dreamforce-2012-devzone-unconference

Comment: https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u=00530000003yfq3&fId=0D530000012yFbQ, if you want to Like it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm one of those poor saps who doesn't get to experience DF :) (So no DF login) Im stuck here in rainy old England!

Comment: Looks like it's already there: http://dfdevzoneunconf.uservoice.com/forums/172153-dreamforce-2012-devzone-unconference/suggestions/3108925-what-is-this-new-fangled-salesforce-stack-exchange

Answer (score 2):

I attended a pre-conference training course and mentioned SFSE as well as other social options. Many class members were not aware of the online options.